# How do I remove a project from Mercurial source control ?

Tags: mercurial

I need to remove a project entirely from Mercurial source control. I am the only programmer who has ever worked on it.

Answer (score 3):

Just delete the '.hg' directory. Everything related to history and source control is in there.

Comment: And make sure you've got a back-up first, just in case you change your mind later.